# When is Stack Exchange holding an event program?

Tags: discussion, events

I have been seeing tech conferences all around, and I wonder why Stack Exchange hasn't held one. Or am I just not aware of any?

Stack Exchange is a big community with huge interest in almost every field. I would be willing to attend one when available.

Comment: It might be nice to see SO have a booth at SCALE, someday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They used to a long while back when they were new. I believe they were called DevDays and ran in 2009 - there was one planned for 2011, but was [cancelled due to low registration numbers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/09/06/devdays-2011-is-cancelled/).

Simply, as with many other things, it just looks like it's just one of those things where the time/effort needed to do it right, at a cost many people can attend, just wasn't a good fit.

Comment: Oh, I see. I hope they bounce back as soon as possible.

Comment: There was only ever one DevDays - the 2009 one. The next planned one was in 2011 and got cancelled.